# jquery delay hover event from initializing

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, delay

I have a header that needs to delay for a certain amount of time on page load, then fade out. [It can be tested here](http://[http://jsfiddle.net/yurcj/][1]). I also add the code:

**html**

```
<header id="main-header">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</header>
```

**css**

```
#main-header {height: 70px;}
#inner {height: 70px; background: red;}
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#inner').stop().delay(2300).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);
    $('#main-header').hover(
    function() {$('#inner').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);},
    function() {$('#inner').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);}
);
});
```

When the cursor hovers over the area, it will fade back in.

Everything works flawlessly if the user waits until the initial delay/fade out is complete, but I am having an issue when the cursor hovers over the header before the initial delay/fade out completes. See the link above.

I am thinking I need to delay the hover from initializing somehow for, in this case, 2300ms.. but if anyone has a better solution, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: insertusernamehere left a good point in the comments to his answers. It most likely does not work in IE7 or 8 because they do not support the `<header>` tag. As far as I can tell, Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9 work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, as it prevents the initial fade out to fire when the user moves over the header in the beginning:

```
$(function() {

    var tictac      = setTimeout( function() { $('#inner').animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500); }, 2300 )

    $('#main-header').hover(
        function() {
            clearTimeout(tictac);   
            $('#inner').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);
        },
        function() { $('#inner').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);}
    );

});
```

And as a note: the initial demo won't work in IE < 9 for it's using HTML5-tags.

Comment: This did not make any difference.

Comment: With the initial script, it starts fading out no matter the user is hovering the header or not. With this the header stays, when the user moves over the header before the initial fade out. But maybe I got you question wrong?

Comment: The initial script that he pasted worked for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9, but did not work in IE7 or 8. Your code did not fix it in IE7 or 8.

Comment: I guess the script won't run in IE7 or IE8 just because he uses a `header`-Tag which is not supported by default in < IE9 (needs CSS reset and html5shim or something)

Comment: That may very well be the case. Please add that your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `<header>` tag which is not available in IE prior to IE9. This is the cause for your script not working prior to IE9. As far as I can tell, It works perfectly for Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 in its current state.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="main-header">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#inner').stop().delay(2300).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);
    $('#main-header').hover(
        function() {$('#inner').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);},
        function() {$('#inner').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);}
    );
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yurcj/2/)